# Give an inductive proof for the following divisibility statement.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I wish to prove that 
$$19 \mid 2^{2^{6n+2}}+3 \ \ \text{for all} \ \  n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$$

This is problem 5 in the book "250 Problems in Elementary Number Theory" (1970) by Waclaw Sierpinski.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say "Attempt at induction proof", but I don't see where you have done that. Please add your initial steps, at least, towards such a proof.

Comment: What does $n$ do in this stuff?

Comment: It is sufficient to prove that $\large 2^{6k+2}\equiv 4\mod 18$ for all non-negative integers $k$ and to do this, consider $\large 2^6\equiv 1\mod 9$

Comment: @Famke I removed the colors from the title. There is no need to use MathJax to empphasize words in the title. Markdown has its own methods to emphasize text (bold or italic) but I cant see any reason to emphasize text here. Check other titles, no one uses colors or emphasizes words in the title.

Comment: @miracle173  I only use color to enlightening his purpose. Yes you are right

Comment: @amWhy I have an answer; which I think thats the exact solution what he wants. But I can't post an answer here, what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $2^7 \equiv 2 \pmod {18} $ ... so $2^{6k+2} \equiv 4 \pmod {18} $.

Now by Fermat $ 2^{18} \equiv 1 \pmod {19}$ ... so $2^{2^{6k+2}} \equiv 2^4 \equiv 16 \pmod {19}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $$2^6\equiv 1\pmod{9}\implies 2^{6k}\equiv 1\pmod{9}\implies 2^{6k+2}\equiv 4\pmod{9}$$ from where (since LHS and RHS are even) $$2^{6k+2}\equiv 4\pmod{18}.$$ That is $$2^{6k+2}=18n+4$$ for some nonnegative integer $n.$ Thus

$$2^{2^{6k+2}}=2^{18n+4}\equiv 2^4\pmod{19}$$ where we have used Fermat's theorem ($2^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{19}\implies 2^{18n}\equiv 1\pmod{19}$). Finally, note that

$$2^4+3=19$$ and we are done.